# What's this button on Calendar.app?

Tags: calendar

On OS X 10.9.5, the Calendar.app toolbar sometimes adds this button:

[image: mystery box]

There's no tooltip, and the Calendar toolbar isn't editable so there's no way to show a label for it.  I can't find anything in the online documentation about it.

I think it has something to do with remote/subscribed calendars, but what, exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the Notifications button.

> The Notifications button shows how many invitations you have. If you don’t have any invitations, it isn’t available.

<sup>Source: [Calendar: Reply to an event or calendar invitation](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH11521)</sup>

The notification button also shows when changes are made to a subscribed calendar. In this case, the standard Accept/Decline/Maybe buttons are replaced by a single OK option to dismiss.