# Calendar notifcation not disappearing

Tags: macos, calendar, notifications, ical

What is this "1" alerting me to? There does not appear to be anything in any of my Calendars that is requiring my attention. How can I get rid of this?

[image]

I'm using a clean installation of Yosemite.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To fix the problem, open Terminal and run (case sensitive):

```
killall Dock
```

This will shut down the Dock, and macOS will reopen the Dock immediately. When the Dock fetches the current state of notifications from Calendar, it will see zero pending notifications, and the badge will not show up.

I've had this issue a few times. MacOS has some sort of bug that causes a badge to show a number of active Calendar notifications, even though there are none in Calendar itself. I've most often seen this issue when someone is sending out multiple calendar invites and updates in a short period (e.g. someone creates a meeting, then sends several updates to change the time, location, notes, etc.). I'll respond to each update one by one, and afterwards the badge will still show a "1", even though the notifications list in Calendar is empty.

This is actually a problem with the Dock. In macOS, the Dock is responsible for showing and updating application icons, including badges, check marks, progress bars and other state information that applications want to display. Occasionally, it seems, the state of the Calendar Dock icons gets corrupted or out of sync with the state of the Calendar itself. (This happens with other applications, too, e.g. Messages.)

Comment: Dock always runs under your user, so you'll never need to `sudo killall`?

Comment: @grgarside: Good point. Editing to reflect that.

Comment: This did not work for me.  @ph4n70m's suggestion below, however, did work. Bad UI there, Apple.

Comment: This doesn't work always, seems like Apple's bad-ui notification counter.

Answer (score 26):

The badge is notifying you of a Calendar notification. There are two cases which causes a badge:

- You've been invited to an event.
- An event on one of your shared calendars has been modified.

To clear the badge, open Calendar and click Notifications [image] on the toolbar, then take action on the notification by selecting Accept/Decline/Maybe on an invitation or OK for a change notification.

Also see [What's this button on Calendar.app?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/164609/whats-this-button-on-calendar-app) regarding the Notifications button on the toolbar.

Comment: Strange. There's no such button in Calendar for me :-/

Comment: @Django What about View → Show Notifications?

Comment: I don't see any such option? http://i.stack.imgur.com/wMCHF.png

Comment: @Django It's greyed out, so you apparently don't have any notifications. This seems like a bug. Try resetting notification settings in System Preferences.

Comment: Wow. This is disappointing. This is a totally clean installation of Yosemite (from a USB installation -- completely wiped the HD). I'll give your suggestion a try.

Comment: I reset the notifications. Quit Calendar and then opened it again. No luck. When I finish work today I'll hope that a hard reset will change its mind. (Sigh, "turning it off and on again".)

Comment: Turning it off and on again fixed things. Sigh.

Comment: I was able to see and clear the notification by this method, but no action was required on my part if I went directly into Google Calendars where I manage that particular calendar.  I had accepted the invite and the details had not changed.

Answer (score 10):

Use this button in the calendar app:

[image]

Comment: I don't see that button in mine.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem in El Capitan 10.11.5 with Calendar 8.0.

Fixed it with a solution based on Django's tip in a previous comment:

1. Quit Calendar
2. Switch off all notifications for Calendar in System Preferences
3. Launch Calendar
4. Switch the notifications back on